# Making fixed sidebar starts scrolling when it reach to the footer

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, reactjs

I have to make a fixed sidebar and it starts scrolling up when it reaches the footer in React.js,
I want to use pure javascript and CSS without using jquery. Please give me some suggestion or help through some code.

Answer (score 0):

I always use "react-sticky-box" in my projects. it's built for react with pure js. bellow you can see an example for what you want. (also read the [documentation](https://react-sticky-box.codecks.io/))

Installation:

```
npm install react-sticky-box
```

Example:

```
import React from "react";
import StickyBox from "react-sticky-box";
const Page = () => (
  <div className="row">
    <StickyBox offsetTop={20} offsetBottom={20}>
      <div>Sidebar</div>
    </StickyBox>
    <div>Content</div>
  </div>
);
```